# Additional models.CharField in Django proxy model

Tags: python, django-models

Can anyone help me with adding an additional models.CharField to my Django cities_light_region table.

This is what i want to implement:

```
class MyRegion(Region):
    state_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='XXX', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Error:
?: (models.E017) Proxy model 'MyRegion' contains model fields.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't make sense. Why are you using a proxy model if you want to add fields? What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with below trick

```
class Model(object):
    '''
    Skip extra field validation "models.E017"
    '''

    @classmethod
    def _check_model(cls):
        errors = []
        return errors

class MyRegion(Model, Region):
    state_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='XXX', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Comment: Overriding an internal-use method and skipping a model check, just like that? What are the potential consequences? There must be a reason why Djanog developers do not allow proxy models to have fields.

Comment: @SergiyKolesnikov  it's trick to achieve the required functionality. It does have consequences. Django won't check for the field level validations. If we know that we intentionally doing it then it won't cause any issues. **The developer must know why & what he/she is doing it.**

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error message say it all : a proxy model cannot contain model fields, for the very obvious reason that [a proxy model is a class that uses the table of another model and only add or override behaviour](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#proxy-models).